# Torch7 Convolutional Neural Network, multiple outputs with probabilities

Tags: lua, machine-learning, deep-learning, torch, conv-neural-network

I'm using Torch7 for image recognition (Convolutionnal Neural Network), when I use the default model, I get one output even if I have 4 output classes. The generated output is the final decision, I want to get the probability for each one of the classes (4), something like:

```
Classe 1 : 75%
Classe 2 : 10%
Classe 3 : 10%
Classe 4 : 5%
```

Here is the code I use for the definition of my model:

```
-- define model to train
model = nn.Sequential()

-- stage 1 : mean suppresion -> filter bank -> squashing -> max pooling
model:add(nn.SpatialConvolutionMM(1, 32, 5, 5))
model:add(nn.Dropout())
model:add(nn.Tanh())
model:add(nn.SpatialMaxPooling(3, 3, 3, 3))
-- stage 2 : mean suppresion -> filter bank -> squashing -> max pooling
model:add(nn.SpatialConvolutionMM(32, 64, 5, 5))
model:add(nn.Dropout())
model:add(nn.Tanh())
model:add(nn.SpatialMaxPooling(2, 2, 2, 2))
-- stage 3 : standard 2-layer MLP:
model:add(nn.Reshape(64*2*2))
model:add(nn.Linear(64*2*2, 200))
--model:add(nn.Dropout())
model:add(nn.Tanh())
model:add(nn.Linear(200, 4))
```

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/doc/transfer.md#softmax

Comment: you need an ```nn.SoftMax()``` if you have mutually exclusive outputs and desire a probabilistic output.